# Could anyone help in writing a test class for this batch class?

Tags: batch, class, delete, document

```
 global class HIPIBatchJobContractRetentionDelete implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

     global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) { 

 String query = 'select Id,contract__r.Id, contentDocumentId, contract__r.Retention__c from contentVersion where contract__r.Retention__c =\'Delete\'';
                  return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
                }


     global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<contentVersion> contentDocId) {

            Set<ID> conDocId = new Set<ID>();
            List<contentDocument> CD_ToDelete = new List<contentDocument>();

            for (contentversion cv : contentDocId) {

                conDocId.add(cv.contentDocumentId);
            }

            if(conDocId !=null){

            CD_ToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM contentDocument where Id IN : conDocId AND parentId = '058f00000005O8WAAU'];
            Delete CD_ToDelete;
            }

        }   

      global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

          system.debug('CD_ToDelete>>>>>>>>>>'); 

           }
```

This is what I have so far but I'm not sure how to proceed:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=TRUE)
public class hipitestrigger
{
    public static testMethod void validateHelloWorld()
    {
        Test.StartTest();
        HIPIBatchJobContractRetention b = new HIPIBatchJobContractRetention();
        database.executebatch(b);
        Test.stopTest();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Krishna your question still lacks a lot of information. Why are you not sure how to proceed ? What functionality do you want to test to work correctly ? What outcomes do you expect ? Consider these aspects, write them down and try to translate that to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IsTest
public class HIPIBatchJobContractRetentionDeleteTest{
    public static testMethod void testBatch() {    
        List<contentDocument> documents = new List<contentDocument>();            
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++){
            contentDocument doc = new contentDocument();
            contentDocument.parentId = '058f00000005O8WAAU';

            documents.add(doc);
        }
        insert documents;

        List<contentVersion> versions = new List<contentVersion>();            
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++){
            contentVersion v = new contentVersion();
            v.contentDocumentId = documents[i].Id;
            v.Retention__c = 'Delete';

            versions.add(v);
        }
        insert versions;

        Test.StartTest();        
        Database.executeBatch(new HIPIBatchJobContractRetentionDelete(), 200);
        Test.StopTest();

        System.AssertEquals(0, [SELECT COUNT() FROM contentDocument]);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer @martin. have you ever work with moving document from one library to another library?

Comment: What do you mean when you say moving document from one library to another?

Comment: means changing document's parent id to another parent id?

Comment: what are the common objects between content version and content workspace ? how they are related